How to block user agents using a RewriteMap?
I'm trying to create an Apache RewriteMap for user agents, but I'm stuck.  This code works fine if the agent is a single word and matches the agent string exactly:
RewriteMap  agent_map "txt:/path/to/deflector_maps/agent.map"
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" !=""
#RewriteCond ${agent_map:%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND
RewriteCond "${agent_map:%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}}" "=-"
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

e.g. performimg this command returns a 403:
curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w "HTTP %{http_code}\n" https://www.my-domain.com --user-agent "AdsTxtCrawlerTP/1.2"

however, this one returns a 200:
curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w "HTTP %{http_code}\n" https://www.my-domain.com --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0;) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; PetalBot;+https://webmaster.petalsearch.com/site/petalbot)"

even though "PetalBot" is in the agent.map.  I'm assuming it has to do with the spaces in the user agent.
How can I rewrite (no pun intended) my deflector map above so that it will catch a user agent that contains the keys I have in the deflector map?  Is this even possible?  RewriteMap's work great for IP addresses and referrers, so I'm hoping it can be used for user agents, as well.
The reason I want to use a deflector map, is that the server doesn't need to be rebooted when I make changes to the map file, so I can add to it programmatically.  The change takes effect immediately!  This is one extremely cool feature that Apache doesn't seem to be promoting.
